# cannot login using google on a blazor app

Tags: blazor, google-oauth

I'm adding google login to my webapp (blazor server). I'm using this piece of code for the login:

At program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication("Cookies")
    .AddCookie(opt =>
    {
        opt.Cookie.Name = "TrySingOutGoogleAuth";
        opt.LoginPath = "/auth/google-login";
    })
    .AddGoogle(opt =>
    {
        opt.ClientId = builder.Configuration["Google:Id"] ?? "Not Found";
        opt.ClientSecret = builder.Configuration["Google:Secret"] ?? "Google secret not found";
        opt.Scope.Add("profile");
        opt.Events.OnCreatingTicket = context =>
        {
            string picuri = context.User.GetProperty("picture").GetString() ?? "No picuri found";
            context.Identity?.AddClaim(new Claim("picture", picuri));

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        };
    });
```

And added a controller for the login:

```
[HttpGet("google-login")]
public async Task<ActionResult> Google()
{
    var properties = new AuthenticationProperties
    {
        RedirectUri = "/"
    };
    return Challenge(properties, GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
}
```

Then when I try to login from the page being debugged (IIS Expres > Chrome) I get to the google form, enter my email then I get prompt with:

> Couldn’t sign you in

> This browser or app may not be secure. Learn more
> Try using a different browser. If you’re already using a supported browser, you can try again to sign in.

Whilst in the console I see:

> [0m[38;5;196m[48;5;226mWARNING![0m
> [0mUsing this console may allow attackers to impersonate you and steal your information using an attack called Self-XSS.
> Do not enter or paste code that you do not understand.[0m
> WARNING: Processing source-maps of 35 took longer than 11000 ms so we continued execution without waiting for all the breakpoints for the script to be set.WARNING: Processing source-maps of 37 took longer than 989.271999999999 ms so we continued execution without waiting for all the breakpoints for the script to be set. The thread 0x3f14 has exited with code 0 (0x0).

I'm very new to the whole topic so assume errors at any point in the process.
If I open on an existing chrome already logged, it does work. If the cookie is already present, it does work (I can retrieve info from the connected user)

Any clue what can be going on here ?

Comment: I had google auth.  pretty sure there was a nuget package for it.  IIRC I had to go to the Google developers' site and apply for the site credentials.